# Sql search from 2 or 3 table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search form where I can search for my webshop products.

1 product can be in multiple categoris, not just in one. I store this in the **termek_katgoria_kapcsolo** table. At insert, it creates as many lines, as the product belong to many categoria.

**Example: The ID 12 product belong to ID 1, ID 2, ID 3 categoria.**

The search sql only look at categoria, when one categoria is selected. Most often, I just search for the products name, I don't sort it to categoris.

How can I write the sql, that if I select a categoria also? I show you the tables on a pic.

```
if($termek_kategoria == 0 ) // Sort to categoria or not only search for product name, id...
{
  $sql = "
    SELECT termek_id, termek_nev, termek_cikkszam, termek_status FROM termek
    WHERE $kereses_helye LIKE '%$kw%' ORDER BY $kereses_rendezes $kereses_sorrend
  ";
}
else
{
  // Sorting for categoria also
  $sql = "
    SELECT termek_id, termek_nev, termek_cikkszam, termek_status FROM termek
    WHERE $kereses_helye LIKE '%$kw%' AND termek_kategoria =
    '$termek_kategoria' ORDER BY $kereses_rendezes $kereses_sorrend
  ";
}
```

[image]

**Update:**

```
$sql = "
  SELECT termek.termek_id, termek.termek_nev, termek.termek_cikkszam, termek.termek_status
  termek_kategoria_kapcsolo.*, termek_kategoria.kat_id
  FROM termek
  LEFT JOIN termek_katgoria_kapcsolo ON termek_kategoria 
  WHERE termek_kategoria_kapcsolo.kat_kapcs_kategoria_id = termek_kategoria.kat_id
  AND termek.termek_id IN (SELECT kat_kapcs_termek_id FROM
  termek_kategoria_kapcsolo WHERE kat_kapcs_kategoria_id = '$termek_kategoria')
";
```

This result:
[image]

Whats going wrong here?

What I want is when I select a categoria, the program give me the products, that are in the selected categoria.

Comment: `How can i write the sql, that if i select a categoria also?` ... what does this mean?

Comment: Sorry, im not good in english. The sql, if i select a categoria also, must get the categoria data from another table or tables. In the product table, the termek_categoria column doesnt exists any more, beacuse i changed the categoria system to multiple. (1 product in multiple categories)

Comment: Please show the following: Your current query, sample input, and expected output.

Comment: The current query is in my question. Now, i can only search in the product table for product ID, name, price....I would like that if i can search for categoria also. Or if i dont write a keyword to search for, just select a categoria, the program list all the procuts that are in the selected categoria.

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem:

```
$sql = 
                   "
                        SELECT 
                            t.termek_id, 
                            t.termek_nev, 
                            t.termek_cikkszam, 
                            t.termek_status,

                            kapcs.kat_kapcs_kategoria_id,
                            kapcs.kat_kapcs_termek_id

                            FROM termek t

                            LEFT JOIN termek_katgoria_kapcsolo kapcs ON kapcs.kat_kapcs_kategoria_id = '$termek_kategoria' 

                        WHERE t.termek_id = kapcs.kat_kapcs_termek_id AND t.$kereses_helye LIKE '%$kw%' ORDER BY t.$kereses_rendezes $kereses_sorrend                           
                   ";
```